Estimate AADT from 15 minutes video data
I have collected 15 minutes of traffic volume count data at peak hour with different locations along a two-directional highway. I want to calculate the Average Annual Daily Traffic (AADT). What is the formula and how should I proceed?
Example Data:



Time
Heavy Truck (3-Axle)
Medium Truck (2-Axle)
Light Truck (Pickup/Small Truck)
Standard/Large Bus/ Double Decker (>40 seats and >36 feet chassis)
Mini-Bus (16-39 seats and < 36 feet chassis)
Microbus (Up to 16 seats)
Utility (Jeep/SUV/Pajero)
Private Car
Baby Taxi/CNG/Auto
Tempo/Human Hauler/Leguna
Motorcycle
Bicycle
Rickshaw
Rickshaw Van
Cart




7:00 - 7:05


2





1
4
11
8


3


7:05 - 7:10

2
1
2
2
1
4


1







7:10 - 7:15

1

2
3

6
7
4
1









How many 15 minute periods occur in 24 hours? Provide some example data but an average should not be too challenging.

Please take a look at the example data. I know if I multiply by 96 I would get 24 hour average vehicle flow data. I want to know is there any formula that I should follow to estimate AADT?

Find total annual traffic and /365 ?
